# javascript object/variable issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below code in angular service

```
this.get = function(url,qParams)
{
    var webresponse = new Object();

    $http.get(url+qParams)
    .success(function(result){
        webresponse.data = result;
        webresponse.state = 1;          
    })
    .error(function(result){
        webresponse.data = result;
        webresponse.state = 0;      
    });

    console.log('webresponse :' + webresponse.data);
    return webresponse;
}
```

In console log shows `webresponse.data` as `undefined`. Please help me to understand why. Is it scope issue?

just to let you know `result` is JSON array and in console log it shows JSON array as expected with all elements in it.

Comment: you should console.log in the success fn

Comment: this is an asynchronous call, the function `get()` not wait until the result come

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Thanks for that clear and concise explanation of the issue. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$http.get()` is an `async` call and your `console.log` is in synchronous fashion, so `console.log` initiated first then your `$http`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli sync fashion means that we are generally use to it (keeping it in a lighter note) in programming means line by line execution and waiting, on the other hand `async` don't wait for a result though generally maintained on event cycles

Comment: Thanks for that Sync/Async difference of $http promise in angular. Probably in knew it and still missed it. This is what happens when you work 14 hours a day...!!!! :)

Comment: @SherebyahTishbi your blocking code is breaking your synchronous life cycle :)

Answer (score 1):

Method calls in `$http` are asynchronous: The result will not be necessarily available after the function `.get()` returns. Please check again the docs for `$http`.

Data in `webresponse` will not be available (i.e. your variable is not set *yet* to anything other than the plain object) but only when the `$http.get` request fetches the data from the server. Such moments are the `.success` trigger, the `.error` trigger, and also a trigger you did not use (and perhaps don't need) called `.finally` (works regardless whether `.success` and `.error` have been triggered).

**You cannot access** the webresponse outside those callbacks since they are the only guaranteed moments where such values will be available. Even more! You cannot RETURN such value from the function. Since the behavior is *asynchronous* you will have to return something in the same *asynchronous* way. Please check the `$q` service to learn how to do it. It is a long topic and you lack the basics on this topic so I will give you some guidelines:

1. `$http` is an asynchronous service. Their calls (e.g. `.get()` return something called a *promise*. Your function should return a promise (either the same or other).
2. The actual result itself (i.e. the result you want) will not be available as you intend: The function's invoker must attend the promise you return, specify a callback for it, and attend it in the callback.
3. More information: You need a deeper knowledge of `$http` and `$q` services. They are pretty well documented in the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

you function is an synchronous call.

```
this.get = function(url,qParams)
{
    var webresponse = new Object();

    $http.get(url+qParams)
    .success(function(result){
        webresponse.data = result;
        webresponse.state = 1;          

        console.log('webresponse :' + webresponse.data);
        //triger any function @here when its success 
    })
    .error(function(result){
        webresponse.data = result;
        webresponse.state = 0;   


        console.log('webresponse :' + webresponse.data);
        //triger any function @here when its fail 

    });    
}
```

Comment: Aww.....how i missed that whole aspect `promise` in angular. Thank you so much friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.get()` function can't return result immediately.

As you know, the $http module use ajax, (AJAX: Asynchronous Javascript and Xml )

so you have to wait for the asynchronous response in your `success` or `error` callback function.

If you want to return the response, please consider `promise` pattern.